# Python Generated txt not recognized by AJAX .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, python-2.7

Using AJAX the webpage updates as expected when the .txt file is manually changed then saved but the webpage does not update automatically after a python 2.7 logfile.close().

The Python code populates jsVar variable then performs the following.

```
logfile = open('jsVar.txt', 'w')
logfile.write(jsVar)
logfile.close()
```

The following AJAX code is in the HTML file as a script.

```
  $(function(){
    $("#todayweather").load("jsVar.txt");
    $("#tomorrowweather").load("jsVar.txt #paragraph1");
    };
```

Problem: The webpage does not update automatically as expected. When I go into the jsVar.txt file using a text editor, make some changes the webpage updates automatically upon saving the file but does not when the python logfile.close() is executed.  Is there another method that should be incorporated in either the python code or the javascript/jquery to get the webpage to update automatically?

Comment: What is the output of  the python? If you run the python then open the file, are the changes actually made?

Comment: The output is a string and yes when the file is opened the changes are there.

Comment: Are you saving the text file then loading the html page, or is the html file open, you update the text file with python, and want the still open html page to show those changes? Your workflow is unclear

Comment: The html file is open first then the python code is executed which updates the text file. Yes I want the still open html page to show changes without having to reload the page.

Comment: The process that runs the python and updates the text file, is this process initiated by the user viewing the open page, like the user clicks a button to update the file? Or, can this process be initiated by some other process or user elsewhere?

Comment: When the python and html are launched there is a map that is brought up on the clients monitor. This map has icons on it that move around based on new data received by the python code. It is a monitoring system that has no UI or buttons. The process is initiated by another process.

Comment: How frequently does the page need to be updated?

Comment: About 500 millisecond.

Comment: Ouch, every half second is quite expensive. Every 2-5 seconds, and you might get away with using ajax. Less than 2 seconds and ajax isnt a very viable option. If you truly need to load new data every 500 milliseconds, youll need to use a background service of some kind. Have a look a [service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)