# How to automatically execute a JavaScript function after a .txt file has updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, python-2.7

Python code periodically updates the string data in a variable then using logfile.open, write & close() saves the data as a txt. When the txt has been saved AJAX.load needs to be able to recognize that an update has occurred then automatically execute a function.  Is there a way to monitor the Python generated txt file for a change? Or monitor its date/time stamp for a change? that could be used to signal that the change has occurred then execute the JavaScript function?

Comment: how does js reach the file?

Comment: Is there a way? Yes. You could have your JS program periodically check the timestamp on the file and see if it's changed, you could have your Python program send a message out to your JS process to tell it to run it's job, etc. This is of course assuming you're running JS in something like Node.js. If you're asking about from the browser then you'll need a WebSockets connection to pass messages back and forth or periodically perform AJAX calls where the server checks on the file.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844680/python-generated-txt-not-recognized-by-ajax-load?noredirect=1#comment66988291_39844680

Comment: @DelightedD0D: we don't know that OP is not using node.js or a` <input type=file>`

Comment: @dandavis What are you talking about? That question is from the same OP asking about the same thing. Where does a `<input type=file>` come into either question??

Comment: @DelightedD0D: didn't notice OP on both. A populated file input can be re-read() to get the new value of a changed file. if it's on the server, one will have to poll or use eventSource or comet.

Comment: @dandavis fair enough, Im not speaking to that, Im just asking him not to repost the same question from yesterday ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using node.js you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/watch, but I doubt it can be used from the browser.

If you're using the browser, you should probably fall back to either polling (if you can afford additional traffic) or watcher on the server side (e.g. with `watch`) + notification to client (e.g. via `socket.io`)